# Inequality $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz}\leq a \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+b|z|,$

Tags: inequality, radicals, absolute-value

How to prove this inequality: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz}\leq a \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+b|z|,$ for all real numbers $x, y, z$ for some non negative values of $a$ and $b.$ What are the minimum values of $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=0$. Hence, $a\geq1$.

Let $x=y=0$. Hence, $b\geq1$.

We'll prove that $a=b=1$ are valid.

Indeed, we need to prove that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+|z|$$ or after squaring of the both sides
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz\leq x^2+y^2+2|z|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+z^2$$ or
$$\sqrt{z^2(x^2+y^2)}\geq yz,$$
which is true because
$$\sqrt{z^2(x^2+y^2)}\geq\sqrt{y^2z^2}=|yz|\geq yz.$$
Done!

Comment: michael, how you got the $\sqrt{z^2(x^2+y^2)}\geq yz$ after squarring?

Comment: @Vijay I'll fix my post. See an editing soon.

Answer (score 0):

We have $2yz\le y^2+z^2$, hence :

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz\le x^2+2y^2+2z^2\le2(x^2+y^2)+2z^2$$

and finally :

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2yz}\le\sqrt2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt2\vert z\vert$$

because, for every $a,b\ge 0$ :

$$\sqrt{a+b}\le\sqrt a+\sqrt b$$

This doesn't prove the minimality ...

Comment: Then how to prove the minimality?